# Connection could not be established with host mailhog

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailtrap

I have this `mail` class that is used to send an email after a `user` is manually `verified` in the admin backend. I copied the credentials from `mailtrap.io` into my `.env` file to test the mail but I got this log when the email class was invoked.

> Swift_TransportException
> Connection could not be established with host mailhog: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

##### Mailtrap credentials

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=secrete
MAIL_PASSWORD=secrete
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Well, I am assuming you are using Laravel 8 because `MAIL_MAILER` is new on Laravel 8. So, it is the basic configuration `mailtrap` gives you. So the error is related to your host not finding the `mailtrap`'s host, like if there is a firewall or a wrong DNS... I am not 100% sure, but it is related to that. Are you running this in a docker container ? If so or not, can you run a `ping` to that host (run it in both container and normal please). If the ping is not responding, try `telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 2525`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti, it's on local host please.